# Please help me convert this script to a simple image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

Can some please, PLEASE! help me with this problem. Okay so I have a code that at first I thought worked well but I forgot that when the default `<img src="test-img-1.jpg" class="actual-img">` content is loaded the first of the three buttons below the image should take the active css state that I've specified for the active buttons to take. Now what I want is for this little code to behave like a normal slider by loading in the css hidden contents into the ".image-area" div and it works when I click on the buttons. Problems only surface when I am I trying to give the first loaded content an active state. One way I believe can fix this (I can't implement it) is to let the first immediate default content be this inline hidden div: (

    `<div id="image-area2">
      <div class="img-area-wrapper">
        <img src="test-img-2.jpg" class="actual-img">
      </div>
    </div>`) while somehow letting the first button be set to active. I should also mention that I'm not the best with jquery. Please help me fix this someone!

Here is a fiddle to get a better understanding: http://jsfiddle.net/pyrot/84sU4/

If my way of going about this is totally absurd please let me know.

this is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    //loads default content
    //$('#image-area').load($('.menu_top a:first-child').attr('href'));

    $('.o-links').click(function() {

      // href has to be the id of the hidden content element
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#image-area').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).html($('#' + href).html()).fadeIn(1000);
        });
      return false;
    });

  });

  $(function() {
      $('.o-links').click(function(e) {

          //e.preventDefault();

          $('.o-links').not(this).removeClass('O_Nav_Current');
          $(this).addClass('O_Nav_Current');
      });
  });
  </script>
```

this is my html:

```
<section id="image-slider-container">
  <div class="image-slider-inner">

    <div id="image-area">
      <div class="img-area-wrapper">
        <!--currently this is the default I want to change-->
        <img src="test-img-1.jpg" class="actual-img">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="image-area2">
      <div class="img-area-wrapper">
        <!--I would like this to be the default content that when
        seen the first button is set to active-->
        <img src="test-img-2.jpg" class="actual-img">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="image-area3">
      <div class="img-area-wrapper">
        <img src="test-img-3.jpg" class="actual-img">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider-buttons">
      <div class="slider-buttons-container">
        <a href="image-area" class="o-links">&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="image-area2" class="o-links">&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="image-area3" class="o-links">&nbsp;</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

and this is my css:

```
#image-slider-container {

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5% 0px 0% 0px;

}

.image-slider-inner {

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;     
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;

}

#image-area2,
#image-area3 {

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: none;

}

#image-area {

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

}

#image-area .img-area-wrapper {

  width: 80%;
  height: auto;     
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0px auto;

}

.actual-img {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}

.slider-buttons {

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin-top: 0px;

}

.slider-buttons-container {

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
  text-align: center;

}

.slider-buttons-container a {

  border-radius: 360px;
  border: 1px #C5C5C5 solid;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  outline: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-shadow: -2px 1px 2px 0px #ADADAD;

  transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;

}


.slider-buttons-container a:hover {

  border: 1px #C5C5C5 solid;
  padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  background-color: #DAD8D8

}

.slider-buttons-container a:active {

  position: relative;
  top: 2px;

}

.O_Nav_Current {

  border: 1px #999999 solid !important;
  background-color: #DAD8D8 !important;

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... You just want the first button to be active on page load? You could put this as the first line of your code: $('.o-links').eq(0).addClass('O_Nav_Current'); // Does that work?

Comment: Shwarz thanks for your help. That solves one part of the problem. The other part is that I would kindly like the of css hidden divs with the images to be displayed as the first default content. Because once the current content that is in the navigation area disappears the buttons below can't go back to it, because that content in the display isn't a smart way of going about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problems only surface when I am I trying to give the first loaded content an active state

Does this mean that you want to add a class to the first button?

```
$('.o-links').click(function(e) {
  // ...
}).first().addClass('O_Nav_Current');
```

instead of using IDs for the slider's items and resetting html contents you can use classes and indexes:

CSS:

```
.image-area {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
}

.image-area:first-of-type {
    display: block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var $slides = $('.image-area'),
    $btns = $('a.o-links');

$btns.on('click', function (e) {
    var i = $btns.removeClass('O_Nav_Current').index(this);
    $(this).addClass('O_Nav_Current');

    $slides.filter(':visible').fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $slides.eq(i).fadeIn(1000);
    });

    e.preventDefault();

}).first().addClass('O_Nav_Current');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RmF57/

Comment: thanks for your response BlackSheep, but I don't just want to add an active class to first button, but I would also want the first div that is hidden with css to display as the first image of the slide on the document load.

Comment: THANKS A LOT, THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR. the fiddle works like a dream. Thanks a lot man. My problem was that I had no way of using the buttons to go back to that first loaded content.

Comment: @user3140116 You are very welcome, I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: Hey, I have one last thing to ask of you. Can you please help me remove the href "a" links so that this uses actual div buttons only please?!

Comment: Oh nevermind that last request I did it. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but when I click on the buttons too quickly your code sort of falls apart. Can you please help me fix it?

Comment: Once more thank you. You don't know how much I appreciate this. You are helping me to keep my job. I'm currently learning jquery but everything is so difficult for me. Do you have any tips? What resources did you use or what book did you read?

Comment: @user3140116 Well, I stated learning JavaScript before jQuery. David Flanagan's [JavaScript book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do) IMHO is the best one. If you want to learn jQuery, http://api.jquery.com is the best resource and also don't forget the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Comment: Hey man thanks! I just downloaded Flanagan's book - it's good, though I was hoping for something with practice exercises. Will be sure to check out the other links. Also someone previously recommended the jquery api to me, so it must be really good. Thanks again. I wish this site had a facebook interface, that way I could probably send you a friend request or something.

Comment: @user3140116 You are welcome, the book has many examples, if you want to read a book with more practical examples you can consider reading JavaScript cookbooks, there are many. Thanks for mentioning this, unfortunately SO is for _robots_ :)

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I'll definitely search for some of those cookbooks and I do really hope SO becomes a more social website in the near future. It's sort of impossible to make friends on this site - it's just hi and bye most of the time.